# Is the range of a covering map normal subgroup of codamin?

Tags: algebraic-topology

> Let $(C,c_0),(X,x_0)$ be topological spaces.
>
> Let $p:(C,c_0)\rightarrow (X,x_0)$ be a covering map.
>
> Let $p_*:\pi_1(C,c_0)\rightarrow \pi_1(X,x_0)$ be the induced homomorphism by $p$.
>
> Then, is it true that $p_*(\pi_1(C,c_0))$ is a normal subgroup of $\pi_1(X,x_0)$?

Let $\phi:\pi_1(X,x_0)\rightarrow p^{-1}(x_0)$ be the lift correspondence of $p$.

Define $H=p_*(\pi_1(C,c_0))$.

Let $\alpha,\gamma$ be loops at $x_0$.

It's a theorem in Munkres-Tolology that: $[\alpha]\in H[\gamma]$ iff $\phi([\alpha])=\phi([\gamma])$.

Doesn't this imply that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $\pi_1(X,x_0)$?

Comment: No. Covers for which this is true are called normal, just as in Galois theory.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan So do you mean that the statement " $[\alpha]\in [\gamma]H$ iff $\phi([\alpha])=\phi([\gamma])$" is false?

Comment: No, I don't mean that. $\phi$ is not a group homomorphism.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Urr.. Does $\phi$ have to be a group homomorphism to make $H$ a normal subgroup of $\pi_1(X,x_0)$?

Comment: Well, that's a reason you might think that $H$ is a normal subgroup. Do you know an explicit example of a non-normal covering? And if that wasn't your reason for thinking that $H$ is  a normal subgroup, then what was?

Comment: I like using the idea of covering morphism of groupoids to model covering map of spaces. See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/159663/functors-and-coverings/159770#159770 . It leads to the question: given a covering morphism of groupoids $q: H \to \pi_1 X$, when is it realised by $H \cong \pi_1 \widetilde{X}$? See "Topology and Groupoids".  A covering morphism is a good algebraic model of a covering map.